# Set proper in image in device respective to their dpi

Tags: android

I am developing app where get one XML . I parse this XML . I get the images name of like logoldpi ,logomdpi ,logohdpi ,logoxh dpi . now I need to set these image according to device dpi.I have set these image acccording to device dpi but in case my device is hdpi and i get logohdpi null then i need to set logomdpi if it is null then logoldpi how to solve this ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make different drawable folders for different resolutions.
Eg ldpi - drawable-ldpi
   hdpi - drawable-hdpi
   mdpi - drawable-mdpi
   xhdpi - drawable-xhdpi

and put the images accordingly in these folders and android os will pick them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks , but in my case i want to know the logic how to implement this if i am not getting image of respective device than i need to set lower dpi image on device

Comment: take that image in only drawable folder.when you dont get any of the image according to the resolution it will pick it from the drawable folder

Comment: Thanks @Sunhail ,but i am getting  image name from xml file at run time. and actually i am downloading a zip file which contain one xml that give the image name as per the device resolution . i need to set proper image if i get that image name null then i need to set lower resolution image name.

Comment: then you can catch the null pointer Exception and do the need full at that time